# $S_{n}=\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{5}{k}$ estimation

Tags: sequences-and-series

It's given the sum

$S_{n}=\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{5}{k}$.

Why can I say $S_{n}>5log(\frac{n+1}{3})$ for $n\geq 3$ ?
I thought I could use the disequation

$\int_{k_0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx \leq \sum_{k=k_0}^{+\infty}f(k) \leq f(k_0)+\int_{k_0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$

but isn't it valid just for infinite series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that,

$$\frac{5}{k}>\int^{k+1}_{k}\frac{5}{x}\,dx$$

Look at the image attached to see why.
$$\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{5}{k}>\int^{n+1}_{3}\frac{5}{x}\,dx = 5\log{\frac{n+1}{3}}$$

[image: harmonic series]

Image source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Comment: If I look at the image I can understand, but how can I justify formally $\frac{5}{k}>\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{5}{x}dx$?

Comment: @Stefan Because for any function $f$, we have $$(b-a)\sup_{x\in [a, b]}f(x)\geq \int_a^b f(x)dx$$ with equality iff $f(x)$ is _equal_ to this supremum value almost everywhere on $[a, b]$. The value $(b-a)\sum_{x\in [a, b]}f(x)$ is an upper sum, and the (Riemann) integral (if it exists) is the infimum of all possible upper sums.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that 
$$
\int_k^{k+1}\frac{5}{x}dx<\frac{5}{k}\\
\Rightarrow\int_3^{n+1}\frac{5}{x}dx<\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{5}{k}
$$

To justify the first line notice that

$$
\int_a^b g(x) dx\geq (b-a)\min_{a\leq x\leq b} g(x)
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I got it, but how can I justify the first line?

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{1}{x} < \dfrac{1}{k}$ for $k < x < k+1$.

Comment: I updated my answer.